# aspnet_regsql - Creating the Application Services Database for mysql or postgresql database

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql-server

I know that it is possible (and straightforward) to create an application services database using a SQL Server database. However, I would like to use another database technology such as MySQL or PostgreSQL for my authentication/role management. I was wondering if there is a similar command to do so for non-mssql databases or if there is a commonly used workaround for doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `aspnet_regsql` program can only create database objects for membership and role management for Microsoft SQL Server databases.

That said it is possible to create your own structures for other database tables and implement your own membership and role provider types (or use someone else's implementations).

For MySQL the [Connector/Net](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.1.html) looks like the best way to go. A search leads to [a blog post about how to use and configure it](http://blog.nolanbailey.com/2008/03/08/mysql-aspnet-membership-and-role-provider/194). Alternatively [you could implement your own](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/mysqlmembershipprovider.aspx), but I would recommend going with the Connector/Net.

I don't have any experience with PostgreSQL but I'd be surprised if there wasn't an existing provider out there. Again, you could implement your own if needed.

Comment: For PostgreSQL, one can find an open source provider here: http://dev.nauck-it.de/projects/aspsqlprovider/ . On the site, look under Wiki -> Installation for more information on how to set it up.